# Can one define two `istream_iterator`s to a single file?

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

```
ifstream file1;
file1.open("in1.txt");
istream_iterator<string> iterator1(file1);
copy(istream_iterator<string>(file1), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(lstr));
```

Can we have two input stream iterators pointing to a single file? As in the above case the iterator is getting advanced (only one time deferencing, as it should be) and first element (string) is missing in the copy. Is there a possible way?

Comment: Wait. _Which_ iterator is getting advanced/dereferenced, and in _what order_??

Comment: iterator that is getting created in the copy function(first argument), does not point to first element in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but if you advance one, the file pointer will advance with it, so it will affect the other one's next advance.  Also, the iterator is advanced once upon creation, so don't create it until you need it.

Comment: What does it mean for an input iterator to "advance"?

Comment: @sbi: std::advance or increment.

Comment: @Fred Isn't that a noop for input iterators?

Comment: @sbi: All input iterators? No. It isn't for istream_iterators either.

Comment: @sbi -- I believe you were thinking of output iterators, where the iterator is advanced upon dereferencing, and incrementing is a no-op.

Comment: @Fred and @Pig: In that case my answer is wrong, which is why I deleted it. I do, however, disagree that "incrementing them is what gets the new value". If that were so, you could dereference an input iterator several times and get the same value. Which you can't.

Comment: @sbi: "After it is constructed, and every time ++ is used, the iterator reads and stores a value of T. ... Every time ++ is used a new value is read." from C++03 §24.5.1p1.

Comment: @PigBen: Thanks, it seems I was completely off the mark. I feel ashamed now. `<hangs_head/>`

Answer (score 1):

The Standard lays it bare at 24.1.1 as a note followed from the requirement rules. And since everyone wants to hear Standardese, I'm quoting it

> [Note: For input iterators, a == b does not imply ++a == ++b. (Equality does not guarantee the substitution property or referential transparency.) Algorithms on input iterators should never attempt to pass through the same iterator twice. They should be single pass algorithms.

Comment: I have no idea what that would mean in plain English. Those standardization guys have no sense for prose at all.